# Need to add constraint: date plus 10 days

Tags: sql, constraints, default, alter, dateadd

I'm trying to add a constraint to a table so that it displays one of the columns as the current date plus 10 days. Here's what I've tried so far (I'm very new to SQL):

```
ALTER TABLE         orders
ADD CONSTRAINT  default_date
DEFAULT         DATEADD (DAY,10,required_date) FOR required_date
```

Halp!

Edit: I've also tried this now:

```
ALTER TABLE         orders
ALTER COLUMN        required_date
ADD CONSTRAINT      required_date_plus_ten
DEFAULT             DATEADD (DAY,10,required_date)
```

Edit: Thanks to ypercube & my classmate. The final code is:

```
ALTER TABLE       orders
ADD CONSTRAINT    default_date
DEFAULT           (DATEADD (DAY,10,'required_date')) FOR required_date;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you sure your want a constraint?  Perhaps you want a calculated column in a view (returning some existing column plus 10 days)...

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft SQL management server. I'm doing a school project and it says to add the constraint: 'required date' (the column name I'm adding the constraint to) should default to today's date plus 10 days.

Comment: then yes the term is being used very loosely and it's actually a calculated field.  Also the constraint can't actually be against the 'current' date or it will never be reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in SQL-Server, for adding a `DEFAULT` value to an existing column is:

```
ALTER TABLE     orders
ADD CONSTRAINT  required_date_plus_ten
DEFAULT         DATEADD(day, 10, GETDATE())
FOR             required_date ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f450b/2)**

Comment: Yes perfect thanks. My classmate has also helped me out with this. I'll post my final code.